# @Cacheable - how to evict object without knowing cache ID?

Tags: java, performance, spring, ehcache

I have a simple Spring application which has a method:

```
@Cacheable("getSession")
public Session getSession(String sessionId) { ...
```

which is backed by eh-cache and works well.  Where I'm having problems is that I need to evict objects from this cache not based on sessionId (a GUID by which they are keyed in the cache) but instead by the database Id of the returned object:

```
public void evictSessionFromCache(long id) { ...
```

There is no way for me to know the sessionId at the point this object needs to be evicted.

Does anybody have any pointers on this?  I've tried extending EhCacheCacheManager to return a wrapped Cache object with a mapping between db ID and sessionID but this feels like a clunky solution:

```
if(name.equals("getSession")) {
    if(wrappedCache == null) {
        wrappedCache = new WrappedCache(super.getCache(name));
    }
    return wrappedCache;
} else {
    return super.getCache(name);
}
```

Are there any properties I can use out of the box to utilise this annotation and access objects by more than one id? Or should I forget the annotation and manipulate the cache / cacheManager directly?

Thanks!

Comment: but when and how you may find which sessionId maps to which db id? (or back way)

Comment: They are linked in the database and the cached objects contain both id's.  Client applications access the session with the sessionId, we get a list of db ids to evict from a database trigger (and want to avoid looking up against the db during an evict).